# What can I do to get rid of MapCheck warnings after moving assets to another location made most objects invisible?

Tags: unreal-engine4, landscape, unreal-engine5

I'm having MapCheck warnings and missing meshes/materials after moving several assets to another folder and fixing redirectors. Maybe there are some types of assets or files associated with landscape that I should never move.

```
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_0 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_1 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_2 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_3 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_4 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_5 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_6 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_7 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_8 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_9 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_10 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_11 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap 
MapCheck: Warning: /Game/Scenes/tutorial_level.tutorial_level:PersistentLevel.Landscape_0.LandscapeComponent_12 : Fixed up deleted layer weightmap
```

I've tried painting information on the landscape and saving it as another scene. Nevertheless, I continue to get these warnings.

[landscape painting mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofQRp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here,
Warnings only on the start, if I check the map from Build > Map Check, so there no warnings.
Have no idea what is, but fixed by resize landscape (with same parameters as it created)
Landscape mode > Resize > Apply
I suggest to try first on the duplicated map

Comment: It solved my issue, thank you :) 
One thing to keep in mind, the RVT textures need to be re-applied to landscape after resizing

Answer (score 0):

Landscape mode > Resize > Apply
I've also set RESIZE MODE > "RESAMPLE"
otherwise my landscape shifts to another position.